Does a self-concordant barrier function exist for every convex continous optimisation problem?
A self-concordant barrier function allows constructing an easy implementation of a newton method related interpoint method.
Do self-condordant barrier functions exist for every convex, continous and optimisation problem where the objective is three-times continuously differentiable?

The fundamental text about self concordant barriers is Interior-Point Polynomial Algorithms in Convex Programming by Nesterov and Nemirovskii, which can be accessed for example here
https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~nemirovs/InteriorPointalgorithmsforConvexProgrammingNestrov&Nemirovski2001.pdf.
I quote from section 2.5:
"In this section, we demonstrate that an arbitrary n-dimensional closed convex
domain admits an O(n)-self-concordant barrier. This barrier is given by certain universal construction and, for this reason, will be called universal. In fact, the universal barrier usually is too complicated to be used in interior-point algorithms, so that what follows should be regarded as nothing but an existence theorem. At the same time, this existence theorem is very important theoretically, since it means that the approach we are developing in principle can be applied to any convex problem."
Have a look at the book for more details and for the proof of the statement.
